# Table-driven CRC calculation where the length of the data is not a multiple of 4

Tags: crc

Is there a way to speed up the CRC process by using a table-driven method when the length of the data is not a multiple of 4? In my problem there are 226 bits to be checked, and a 24 bit-checksum is calculated for this by CRC24Q algorithm.

Comment: Are you sure the table lookup is faster than pure processor crc calculation for a 226bits set ? for this testcase I bet on processor.

Comment: Byte-wise processing is said to work faster than the bit-wise one in some documents, but I am not sure which one is better. I hope to figure out here.

Comment: The faster way is maybe to move to CRC32 (zip,ethernet,mpeg...) which is processor accelerated on modern cpu, I guess it will be hard to do better. http://byteworm.com/2010/10/13/crc32/ http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/fast-parallelized-crc-computation-using/229401411

Comment: I can't do that since I'm working on satellite data.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the crc for the first part using a table and then add the tail's crc to the result